# How can i check if a single mysql field is empty in php

Tags: php, mysql

After getting the user-info from my sql database I would like to check if some of the fields are empty and continue the script based on that. A simplified piece of code would look like this:

```
$userData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='".$user."' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($data) == 1){

    $u_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

    if(empty($u_info['u_mobile'])){
        echo 2;
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 1;
        exit();
    }

} else {

    echo 3;
    exit();
}
```

The problem is the empty statement checking the recieved field. I've tried using empty(), isset(), not_null() and array_key_exists() with no luck and can't get around to what I'm doing wrong. 
I also tried `if($u_info['u_mobile']) == '' || $u_info['u_mobile']) == NULL)` but that doesnæt work either.

Why is this, or how can I go about getting this information?

I need to collect the user-information and send them to fill out the information I don't have...

Comment: can you add the `var_dump($u_info)` to see if you are getting the correct row? "does not work" means the field is blank and you are not being displayed the correct text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the query result to `$userData` but then you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc($data);` -- doh. You need to pass the variable that you set the query result to:

```
$u_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData);
```

It's OK, it is still 10AM EST so this can happen in the morning =)
I suggest that you turn on PHP error reporting. PHP would have alerted you that the array values were trying to access do not exist, saving you a lot of wasted frustration.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$userData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='".$user."' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($userData ) == 1){

    $u_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData );

    if(empty($u_info['u_mobile'])){
        echo 2;
        exit();
    } else {
        echo 1;
        exit();
    }

} else {

    echo 3;
    exit();
}
```

Please Run code..I think it will be compile better it was minor mistake